# How to write regular expression in Julia that contains plus?

Tags: regex, julia

I have a string

```
a="250010.E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E-00"
```

Now I hope to use regular expression to get

```
re=r"(?<b>[A-Z0-9.-]+)\s+(?<c>[A-Z0-9.-]+)\s+(?<d>[A-Z0-9.-]+)"
```

How to add "+" in to the re? \+ doesn't work. It means the phrase must contain "+".

```
RegexMatch("250010.E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E-00", b="250010.E-03", c="0.0000E+00", d="0.0000E-00")
```

Comment: I found that if put \\+ in the begining, like  [\\+A-Z0-9.-], it works. But if put \\+ in the end, like [A-Z0-9.-\\+], it means the phrase must contain +. Strange to me.

Comment: `[.-\\+]` (dot, hyphen, escaped backslash, plus) doesn't work as you expect because `.-\ ` forms a valid range. If you escape `-` properly the position of `+` is unimportant: [`[.\-+]`](https://regex101.com/r/rKtUwF/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like InSync said, you need to escape the dashes as well as the periods. The issue isn't that + doesn't work, it's that unescaped dashes (when you're looking for a dash) doesn't work.

Also I don't believe you need to double escape them, as this isn't R.

Code:

```
re=r"(?<b>[A-Z0-9\.\-+]+)\s+(?<c>[A-Z0-9\.\-+]+)\s+(?<d>[A-Z0-9\.\-+]+)"

matches = match(re,a).captures

# turn the numbers into floats
parse.(Float64,matches)

# 3-element Vector{Float64}:
# 250.01
#  0.0
#  0.0
```